# Are there any approaches/suggestiosn for classifying a keyword so the search space will be reduced in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, text-classification

I was wondering is there any way to classify a single word before applying a search on elasticsearch. Let's say I have 4 indexes each one holds few millions documents about a specific category.

[image]

I'd like to avoid searching the whole search space each time. 
This problem becomes more challenging since it's not a sentence, 
The search query usually consists only a single or two words, so some nlp `magic` (Named-entity recognition, POS etc) can't be applied.

I have read few questions on stackoverflow like:

[Semantic search with NLP and elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772692/semantic-search-with-nlp-and-elasticsearch)

[Identifying a person's name vs. a dictionary word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290667/identifying-a-persons-name-vs-a-dictionary-word)

and few more, but couldn't find an approach. are there any suggestions I should try?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve ? Do you want to perform word classification using elasticsearch or do you have already a solution to classify queries ?

Comment: @Pierre-Nicolas Mougel I'd like to find a way to classify the query which holds one or two words (I haven't found yet a way to classify queries).

Comment: @JammingThebBits Were you able to find a solution or any workaround? Could you please share it?

Comment: @Yashwanth  I left it, wasn't able to solve it.